# Handling yum upgrade from pkg-x.y.rpm which requires mod_python to pkg-x.(y+z).rpm with conflicts mod_python

Tags: centos5, yum, rhel5, rpm

With yum/rpm on RHEL 5 can a `yum upgrade` be made to remove another, conflicting package - similar to the behaviour of `apt-get dist-upgrade` on Debian?

I am updating the .spec for our product's rpm. Version 4.2.x used mod_python, so the spec contained

```
Requires: mod_python
```

version 4.3.x uses mod_wsgi in daemon mode, and thus is [incompatible with having mod_python loaded simultaneously](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Incompatible_ModPython_Versions) (as packaged in RHEL 5.x). To make sure mod_python is not loaded in version 4.3.x we've tried to use

```
Conflicts: mod_python
```

I was hoping that this would allow yum to realise it could remove mod_python at the time of upgrade, but it refuses and I cannot find a way to configure/instruct yum otherwise

```
[root@server ~]# yum upgrade define
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin, security
Skipping security plugin, no data
Setting up Upgrade Process
Resolving Dependencies
Skipping security plugin, no data
--> Running transaction check
---> Package define.x86_64 0:4.3.14-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: shibboleth for package: define
--> Running transaction check
---> Package shibboleth.x86_64 0:2.4.3-2.2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: opensaml-schemas for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: xmltooling-schemas for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: libxmltooling-lite.so.5()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: libxerces-c-3.1.so()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: libsaml.so.7()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: liblog4shib.so.1()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.1()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: libxml-security-c.so.16()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Processing Dependency: libxmltooling.so.5()(64bit) for package: shibboleth
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsaml7.x86_64 0:2.4.3-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libxerces-c-3_1.x86_64 0:3.1.1-2.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libxml-security-c16.x86_64 0:1.6.1-3.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libxmltooling5.x86_64 0:1.4.2-2.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package log4shib.x86_64 0:1.0.3-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package opensaml-schemas.x86_64 0:2.4.3-3.2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package unixODBC-libs.x86_64 0:2.2.11-10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package xmltooling-schemas.x86_64 0:1.4.2-2.1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: define conflicts mod_python
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
define-4.3.14-1.x86_64 from define-development has depsolving problems
  --> define conflicts with mod_python
Error: define conflicts with mod_python
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

At the moment I'm using

```
yum remove define; yum remove mod_python; yum install define
```

as a workaround. Is there a better way to handle this (upgrade foo triggers removal of bar) with yum/rpm? Or is the answer "this is something you aren't meant to do on RHEL, so don't do it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think yum can do this; the only way out of a conflict is to prep the system to avoid it. It's possible a plugin could modify yum's behaviour and propose package removal to resolve the conflict, but I'm not aware of one.